# How to delete photo from iPhone photo library

Tags: iphone

Is there any method to delete the photo(s) from the photo library. (NOTE: I dont want to copy the images into the document directory (sandbox), and then delete it from there; I want to refer the actual image from photo library)

I have different considerations, but I am not sure anyone from these will work or not (or if these are feasible):-

1) Getting URL of the UIImage selected, and then delete it or modify the bytes of that file to 0 size or empty.

2) Using Assets library, delete the image from photo library itself.

I want to make sure if any approach from above will work or not, or do I need something else to delete/modify the image in photo library?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delete a photo from the user's photo library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172978/delete-a-photo-from-the-users-photo-library)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not appear to be any way to do this in the published APIs. Your first idea won't work, as the URLs returned by AssetsLibrary are opaque and cannot be used to access the files on disk. And if they catch you poking around the filesystem trying to delete images outside of your app's directory (if the permissions don't lock it down anyway), you'll be denied. As for the second, there just is no function to do so.

It's too bad, we could use it in our app too.

Comment: Hmm. I posted it on the apple forums too, and they replied the same. Thanks