# I want to delete image from photo library programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image

I want to delete image from photo library or replace cropped image instead of that original image. Is it possible in iphone?

Comment: Please check answer of [Delete a photo from the user's photo library][1]? 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172978/delete-a-photo-from-the-users-photo-library

Comment: @user1831389 here you question should be like ,this how to cropped any image captured image and want to save in photoLibrary?.am i right..if you so i ma gonna edit your question

Comment: It is possible from iOS 8, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142061/is-is-possible-to-delete-photos-from-cameraroll-programmatically

Answer (score 3):

You can't allow to delete any image of `PhotoLibrary` Through The Code , you can do this by reaching there directly in the PhotoLibrary Application.

This is Completed restricted by The Apple.See few Lines of Apple Documentation regarding the same.

`To save a still image to the user’s Saved Photos album, use the UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum function. To save a movie to the user’s Saved Photos album, use the UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum function.`